# QT application with admin privileges can't edit text file on startup

Tags: qt, admin, startup

I have created an application that is designed to startup, complete a form on my university website to allow access through the proxy for applications like google drive and steam (lel). It accesses a text file in the program directory to obtain the username and password (encrypted obviously). I've made it run on startup by adding it to the startup programs in the registry.

WINDOWS 7 WORKS PERFECTLY.

Here is what happens IN WINDOWS 8.1:

*Opening it from explorer manually, the program works as expected, accessing the username and password and automatically logging in. Running as admin also works perfectly.

*Allowing it to run on start up causes the program to give an error saying it can't read/write the file with the password in it, making me have to manually enter the username and password in. All folders/file in the program directory are all read/write enabled.

*Giving the program administrator rights by including a manifest file when compiling (has the UAC logo on the icon, so I know it has worked) or giving it admin rights via the .exe properties - opening it manually from explorer works perfectly, however on startup it won't even start the application.

Does anyone know the reason for my observations?

Registry command:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.setValue("BorderAuth.exe", QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath().replace('/','\\'));
```

BorderAuth.exe.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="BorderAuth"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Opens and closes the border of the network</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

.rc file:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "icon_blue.ico"
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "BorderAuth.exe.manifest"
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets webkitwidgets

TARGET = BorderAuth
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    settings.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    settings.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    settings.ui

RESOURCES += \
    icons.qrc

RC_FILE = icon.rc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something starting an application that requires elevation via the registry sounds a little fishy. Are you sure UAC is enabled on the Win 7 machine? If so, does it prompt you for approval every time you start your computer?

Comment: @MrEricSir. All it does is adds the program to the startup list. It's the easiest way to add and remove it from the list since the user settings has this option. How would you recommend adding/removing the program to run at startup? My account is admin and UAC is off. I figured when the system opens the program, it would have administrative rights. I don't understand why it can't write to the file when the system opens it. Both my user account and SYSTEM has "Full Control" over the .exe and .cfg file.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense -- if UAC is off an admin user can write anywhere on the file system without elevation. The problem isn't related to Windows 7 vs. Windows 8 at all. What you should consider doing is installing your program as a service, and setting that service to run at startup.